# htaccess rewrite rule: abc.com/sub/random.php to abc.com/random

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite http://abc.com/sub/random.php to http://abc.com/random.
I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^random$ sub/random.php [QSA,L]
```

But it does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to show the "ugly" URL with the resource in the browser's address bar: `http://abc.com/sub/random.php`, while hiding the "pretty" URL `http://abc.com/random`. So, I assumed you want the opposite of what you asked.

If that is correct, you may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/([^/]+)/?$    [NC]
RewriteRule .* sub/%1.php  [L,QSA]
```

It will map silently this:

`http://abc.com/random`

To this:

`http://abc.com/sub/random.php`

Where `random` is not a fixed string but a variable that is passed as the name of the script.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^sub\/random\.php$ "http\:\/\/abc\.com\/random" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately, it didn't work for some reason.